# Compiling error when running stream word count in the flink-streaming-scala_2.11 module

Tags: apache-flink

I git clone the Flink project from git with Intellij Idea.

I am able to run the batch work count `org.apache.flink.examples.scala.wordcount.WordCount` in the module `flink-examples-batch_2.11` successfully.

But when I try to run the stream word count `org.apache.flink.streaming.scala.examples.wordcount.WordCount` in the module `flink-examples-streaming_2.11`, A couple of compiling errors occur:

```
D:\projects\BigData_Projects\flink\flink-streaming-scala\src\test\scala\org\apache\flink\streaming\api\scala\SideOutputITCase.scala
Error:(30, 30) object streaming is not a member of package org.apache.flink.test
import org.apache.flink.test.streaming.runtime.util.TestListResultSink
Error:(46, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(47, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[Int]
Error:(82, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(83, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[Int]
Error:(119, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(120, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[Int]
Error:(152, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(153, 30) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val lateResultSink = new TestListResultSink[(String, Int)]
Error:(196, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(197, 30) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val lateResultSink = new TestListResultSink[(String, Int)]
Error:(242, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(243, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(289, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(290, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
D:\projects\BigData_Projects\flink\flink-streaming-scala\src\test\scala\org\apache\flink\streaming\api\scala\StreamingScalaAPICompletenessTest.scala
Error:(22, 35) object completeness is not a member of package org.apache.flink.api.scala
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.completeness.ScalaAPICompletenessTestBase
Error:(32, 49) not found: type ScalaAPICompletenessTestBase
class StreamingScalaAPICompletenessTest extends ScalaAPICompletenessTestBase {
Error:(101, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods("DataStream", "DataStream", classOf[JavaStream[_]], classOf[DataStream[_]])
Error:(103, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods(
Error:(108, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods(
Error:(113, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods(
Error:(118, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods(
Error:(123, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods(
Error:(128, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods(
Error:(133, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods(
Error:(138, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods(
Error:(143, 5) not found: value checkMethods
    checkMethods(
```

I am not sure what's wrong there, could some one help? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify which version of Flink you are using, and how you tried to run the streaming word count example?

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson for the reply. I git clone the latest code from github(the master branch) ,and open it with Intellij Idea as a Maven project, and then run it directly in Intellij Idea. I am able to run the batch mode word count: `I am able to run the batch work count org.apache.flink.examples.scala.wordcount.WordCount in the module flink-examples-batch_2.11 successfully.`